# C# BouncyCastle EC Private Key Export Using PemWriter

Tags: c#, cryptography, bouncycastle, pem, key-pair

I'm generating an EC key pair in C# BouncyCastle and trying to export the private key in a PEM file using the PemWriter.  The code for doing so is as follows:

```
var ecKeyPairGenerator = new ECKeyPairGenerator();
CKeyGenerationParameters ecKeyGenParams = new ECKeyGenerationParameters(SecObjectIdentifiers.SecP384r1, new SecureRandom());
ecKeyPairGenerator.Init(ecKeyGenParams);
AsymmetricCipherKeyPair pair = ecKeyPairGenerator.GenerateKeyPair();

string path = @"c:\tmp\test\myprivkey.pem";
TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(path);
PemWriter pemWriter = new PemWriter(textWriter);
// passing pair results in the private key being written out
pemWriter.WriteObject(pair);
pemWriter.Writer.Flush();
pemWriter.Writer.Close();
```

An example output from the snippet above is:

```
-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----
MD4CAQEEMJvNXtTUd7A/fY/9/LSXM+Xb/6QS7GydeART/OieN3zh23Uuy0tgiS1D
rohXMgiPvqAHBgUrgQQAIg==
-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----
```

However, when doing the same thing using 'openssl' and the same EC curve (secp384r1), the resulting PEM file is quite different, e.g.,:

```
openssl ecparam -name secp384r1 -genkey -out mykey2.pem -noout

-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----
MIGkAgEBBDBqCE9+AWL56cvR2/tRNdyaTIlJnfr6TbhCG+Q48w6yyKR+hE0jkeOV
7yh1t8NwqT6gBwYFK4EEACKhZANiAAS2uLv7KG6RRBZBOecaxBz8FsMobnxgZkbQ
8cKdL1DRym1lUDwgfX8AxOC6qkuD1k0UekpHcwiy1mSghy4640qBAKcR3mVghMVF
77Nm8x6nwNijWZroeqhjrw268PPPuAw=
-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----
```

As you can see, the key length is very different, and the P12 file I create with the former doesn't get imported into the Windows cert stores.  I must be doing something wrong with C# BouncyCastle but can't see what (looking at the source code of the PemWriter and other related classes doesn't point to any obvious errors).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: When examining the BC-generated private key PEM file with openssl, openssl correctly reports "Private-Key," "ASN1 OID," and "NIST CURVE" fields, the latter two having the same values as those of the PEM file generated by openssl. Yet, CertUtil fails to "dump" the P12 file created with the BC-generated private key PEM while successfully doing so with the P12 created with the openssl-generated private key PEM.

Comment: They are probably using encodings of different asn.1 types. Try to run `openssl asn1parse -i -dump -i key.pem` on both keys to check that.

Comment: @mat Yes, I was just doing that.  It seems as if the BC PEM file is missing the actual key??  The ans1parse output of the openssl PEM file has an extra structure, which is missing from the BC PEM file.  That structure looks like:
**...
   65:d=1  hl=2 l= 100 cons:  cont [ 1 ]
   67:d=2  hl=2 l=  98 prim:   BIT STRING
...**
This structure is at the end of the openssl PEM file, and the rest of the file leading up to this structure is the same as those in the BC file.  How do I find the asn.1 types of the PEM files?

Comment: The BC PEM contains only the private key, the openssl version contains the public key, too.

Comment: @mat Thanks.  RFC 5915 also confirms that the BC PEM does not have the public key while the openssl PEM does.  And it seems CertUtil wants the public key in a P12 rather than compute it if missing....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out you can create an instance of ECPrivateKeyStructure with both private and public keys and save the Base64-encoded string of the object to file, e.g.,:

```
...
int orderBitLength = privKeyParam.Parameters.N.BitLength;
X962Parameters x962 = new X962Parameters(privKeyParam.PublicKeyParamSet);
ECPrivateKeyStructure privKeyStruct = 
                    new ECPrivateKeyStructure(orderBitLength, privKeyParam.D, pubKeyInfo.PublicKeyData, x962);

string header = @"-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----";
string privKeyStr = Convert.ToBase64String(privKeyStruct.GetDerEncoded(), 
                    Base64FormattingOptions.InsertLineBreaks);
string tail = @"-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----";

string path = @"c:\tmp\myprivkey.pem";
TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(path);
textWriter.WriteLine(header);
textWriter.WriteLine(privKeyStr);
textWriter.WriteLine(tail);
textWriter.Flush();
textWriter.Close();
...
```

Answer (score 1):

A little late to the party, you could write the private and public key explicitly (maybe it is better to use a separate file):

```
...
// passing pair results in the private key being written out
pemWriter.WriteObject(pair.Private);
pemWriter.WriteObject(pair.Public);
pemWriter.Writer.Flush();
pemWriter.Writer.Close();
```

However, the current Version of Bouncy Castle (1.8.5) already writes the public key into the (private key) PEM file. So you should not need to write the public key explicitly.

Additionally, both of the following lines are basically the same:

```
 pemWriter.WriteObject(pair);
 pemWriter.WriteObject(pair.Private);
```

as can be seen in the sourcecode:

```
# .../BouncyCastle/.../MiscPemGenerator.cs
private static PemObject CreatePemObject(...)
{
  ...
  if (obj is AsymmetricCipherKeyPair)
    return MiscPemGenerator.CreatePemObject((object)
      ((AsymmetricCipherKeyPair) obj).Private,
      algorithm, password, random);
  ...
}
```